# Javap Command Error in Java On Command Prompt

Tags: java, package, command, javap

Why javap command is not running in command prompt and its showing javap is not recognised as internal or external command except javap all other command is running well.

Comment: You need to add the jkd/bin folder to your path.

Comment: already did and  all other commands running

Comment: Once you add JDK/bin to your PATH, you need to launch a new command prompt to pick changes. If this does not help, can you share the output of the "PATH" environment variable?

Comment: Perhaps your Java installation is incomplete? This command should list a single file: `ls $JAVA_HOME/bin/javap`. If it doesn't, then javap itself isn't there.